# No overload for method 'Reset' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a VB game to C# and the original VB code is

```
FileSystem.Reset(position, spriteEffect);
```

Visual Studio 2017 is complaining that there is error: CS1501: No overload for method 'Reset' takes 2 arguments. Anyone help me out?

Comment: The [Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.reset(v=vs.110)/html) method in `Microsoft.VisualBasic` doesn't have any parameters. And I am not aware of a FileSystem class in .NET. Could you please provide more context?

Comment: There is no `FileSystem.Reset()` in VB6 to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[FileSystem.Reset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.reset(v=vs.110).aspx) is declared in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace located in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Assembly.

I'm afraid you won't be able to just copy paste, you will need to rewrite this portion of the code.

Comment: Surely he can include a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll in the C# project, even if that turns out to be a temporary or expedient step.